# Can anyone explaing how this answer is calculated?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("%x", -1<<1);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Output:
Output is dependent on the compiler. For 32 bit compiler it would be fffffffe and for 16 bit it would be fffe.

This is from geek for geeks

Comment: Better: `-1U << 1`, see [C11 6.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7)

Answer (score 1):

`-1` is a signed integer. A left shift on a signed integer with a negative value has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) according to the formal definition of the C language. This is part of the general rule that signed operations have undefined behavior when they overflow. the sign bit is set, and it must shift, but there's no room for it to go anywhere, so it overflows.

In practice, almost all platforms use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation for signed integers, and a left shift on a signed integer is treated as if the memory contained an unsigned integer. However, beware that compilers sometimes take advantage of the fact that this is undefined behavior to optimize in surprising ways.

`-1` is all-bits-one, so a left shift drops the topmost bit and adds a 0 bit to the bottom. The result is `111…1110` in binary. If `unsigned int` is a 16-bit type, that's `fffe` in hexadecimal. If `unsigned int` is a 32-bit type, that's `fffffffe`. When that memory is read as a signed `int`, the value is `-2` either way.

The `%x` specified requires an `unsigned int` as an argument. Passing an the signed version of the type is ok: it is converted to the unsigned value. The result of the conversion is 2^N - 2 where N is the number of bits in an `unsigned int`: as above, that's `0xfffe` if N=16, `0xfffffffe` if N=32.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It seems to me this answer is is just your 32-bit compiler casting (implicitly) `-1` as `long int` for a signed integer, while the 16-bit compiler casts `1` to a "good old" `int` 16 bit integer.</strike>

Bad answer. A much better answer is given above by Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'. I am just editing this so it is not absolute non-sense.

As commented above, `-1` is a signed integer, and left shifting (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C#Left_shift_%3C%3C)) a signed integer that is negative causes an undefined behavior because the sign bit has nowhere to go. In all the systems I have worked, that behavior is an overflow.

The reason why the results are different between 16-bit and 32-bit compilers might well just be the fact that 16-bit compilers use 16-bit integers, hence the 16 bit result `fffe`. I attached some code for you to try it out it find it would be useful.

Attached dirty test.

```
/* dirty_test.c
 * This program left bit-shifts a signed integer and
 * prints the byte content of the result to stdout.
 *
 * On *nix like systems, compile with
 *
 * cc dirty_test.c -o dirty_test.x
 */
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int a;
    // assigning a negative value causes the bit shift 
    // to produce an overflow.
    a = -1;
    printf("bytes before shift: %08x\n", a);
    printf("bytes after shift: %08x\n", a << 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `long` involved. That would not be correct for a C compiler, and it would it not explain anything about the behavior reported in the question anyway.

Comment: I agree my answer is indeed wrong and confusing. I must have been very sleepy. I will try not to answer ill-written answer anymore. I edited to be along the lines of what you wrote (which is what I was thinking anyways). My apologies for writing such a silly thing. - Pedro